# How do I make site info appear in the address bar of a browser

Tags: browser

I saw this : [image]

Some site info appears. I use https and i only see "secure" on this place. How do they do this?

Comment: You need an Extended Validation SSL certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certificates with extended verification.
These are the most expensive certificates and get them the hardest. In such certificates there is a so-called "green bar" - that is, at the entrance is not a site where such a certificate is installed in the address bar of the visitor's browser, a green line appears in which the name of the organization that received the certificate will be indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I seems that is a [feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40333828/adding-text-to-the-view-site-information-section-of-the-address-bar) of specific browsers. It would seem that you have no control over the content.